# How do I display an avatar in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating a blog where the author has there own page of titles they have written and would like to display an avatar and email address. How would i go about doing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://gravatar.com has grown in popularity recently, it is used on stackoverflow and github.

You use an md5 hash of the email address to show the avatar.

Usage:

```
require 'digest/md5'
"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest("Email Address".downcase)}?s=128"
```

Result:

```
http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/012f4052c6fb1a600a3e4f39e1f2439a?s=128
```

[image: http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/012f4052c6fb1a600a3e4f39e1f2439a?s=128]

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to use [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip). It's very simple to use and you can display the same picture in multiple sizes. For instance, similarly to SO you can show smaller avatars when on a question page, and bigger avatars when you're on a user's info page.

**Example**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, 
                    :styles => { :large_avatar => "300x300>", 
                                 :small_avatar => "100x100>" }
end
```

You would only need to add that to your model, and then a few extra columns for the migration. My point is that there's not a lot of overhead in using the solution. You will have to include a few other parameters for the forms you use to submit a file url, etc., but it's really simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you have their email address information, I'd recommend using [Gravatar](http://www.gravatar.com).

In essence, you create an md5 hash of their e-mail address (after converting it to all lower-case characters) and use that to build an image URL.

They have plugins for many blog engines, and it's very straight forward to implement without a plugin. See their [Developer Resources](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/) page.